# imlementation hint for a proxy-like System between C / Java

Tags: java, c

I have to say that my question might sound very <strike>shallow</strike> vague, I can't explain it well enough I think. But I will try!

I have a hardware box running on Linux and using C implementation to handle the functionality of the box. I can connect the box to my Laptop via Ethernet, on the Laptop I create higher Layer input for the box.

How can I put this input through to the box?

I might need some light-weight implementation of a proxy, right?

What would be a fast and easy way to do that?

**additional information:**
On Java side I create ASN1 structures and encode them. These structures I want to pass via Ethernet into my little box, which will send out the data via wlan. Oh man, I realise that my knowledge maybe isn't enough to explain that problem. Ok... Hmm, I am done with encoding the ASN1 structures, but from that point I have no idea how to go on. Somehow there must be a way to indicate to the box that new data is passed through and the box should send it out. maybe like a remote proxy, calling methods in Java but they are executed as C-methods inside the box. Basically a transfer system is needed to pass information out of a Java environment into a C environment over Ethernet. Wooo, possible?

Thanks in advance.
nyyrikki

Comment: I think you mean *vague* not shallow. And you're right, I don't get what you're asking :)

Comment: It sounds like you want your "C implementation" to provide a socket service. e.g. a HTTP service, which can accessed across the network.  How do you see Java fitting into this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the input will go through Ethernet, I assume data will be encapsulated within packets.

I have no idea what your input data looks like, but I suggest using the Jpcap (available here : http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/).

Once you've messed around a bit with the API, it is really easy to learn and use.
I've personnaly used it a couple of times, and I have created a "Router" which acted as an ARP proxy. This lets me think you could use this library to achieve what you've explained.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Long time no see :)
I finally ended up using sockets, works well.

Thanks anyways, nyyrikki